# _link method in universal analytics

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I used _link method with classic google analytics.
this is an example:

```
<a class="cart" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', '']); return false;"></a>
```

I want to know what is the equivalent method in universal google analytics

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this in UA:

1. Auto link
2. Link decorator

The first method automatically links based on the domains entered:

```
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['domain1.com','domain2.com']);
```

The second method is to manually decorate the links your links

```
// Loads the Linker plugin
ga('require', 'linker');

// Gets a reference to a link pointing to an external domain.
var destinationLink = document.getElementById('destination-link');

// Adds click handler that decorates `destinationLink`.
destinationLink.addEventListener('click', function() {
  ga('linker:decorate', destinationLink);
});
```

Both are described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker).

Comment: thanks! 
In websites that uses universal, I defined the first method that you wrote.
if I will remove the _link function only in the universal (remove the onclick event) and keep it in websites that use classic analitics, it will be okay?

Comment: I believe that should still work. Just to be make sure I understand you, for your classic GA sites, you would just continue using what you have in your original code?